# Build a Model From Stream (Exception: Reader not found on classpath)

Tags: java, osgi, h2, jena

I’m just trying to add my ontology to the DB repository ……

My code is:

```
oConnection = H2Db.getM_oConnection();
m_oSDBConnection = new SDBConnection(oConnection);
StoreDesc oStoreDesc = new StoreDesc(LayoutType.LayoutTripleNodesHash, DatabaseType.H2);
m_oStore = SDBFactory.connectStore(m_oSDBConnection, oStoreDesc);
m_oModel = SDBFactory.connectDefaultModel(m_oStore);
InputStream oInputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/betaas_context.owl");
m_oModel.read(oInputStream, null);
```

At the beginning with the following dependencies:

```
ID   State         Blueprint      Level  Name
[ 994] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] H2 Database Engine (1.3.170)
[1114] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] wrap_mvn_org.apache.jena_jena-iri_1.0.0 (0)
[1223] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] wrap_mvn_org.apache.jena_jena-arq_2.11.0 (0) -> contains package org.apache.jena.riot.adapters
[1279] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] wrap_mvn_org.apache.jena_jena-core_2.11.0 (0)
[1311] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] wrap_mvn_xerces_xercesImpl_2.7.1 (0)
[1314] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] wrap_mvn_com.ibm.icu_icu4j_3.4.4 (0)
```

And I get this exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.ConfigException: Reader not found on classpath
Caused by: com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.ConfigException: Reader not found on classpath
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.JenaReadersWriters$RDFReaderRIOT_RDFXML
```

And the problem was with the following line:**oModel.read(oInputStream, null);**

***EDIT***

Then, following the suggestion mentioned by AndyS(see bellow), I updated my Jena libraries and used the 2.11.1-SNAPSHOT:

```
[1511] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] wrap_mvn_org.apache.jena_jena-core_2.11.1-SNAPSHOT (0)
[1512] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] wrap_mvn_org.apache.jena_jena-arq_2.11.1-SNAPSHOT (0)
[1515] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] wrap_mvn_org.apache.jena_jena-sdb_1.4.1-SNAPSHOT (0)
[1516] [Resolved   ] [            ] [   80] wrap_mvn_xerces_xercesImpl_2.11.0 (0)
[1521] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] wrap_mvn_org.apache.jena_jena-iri_1.0.1-SNAPSHOT (0)
```

But the exception is the same:
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.JenaReadersWriters$RDFReaderRIOT_RDFXML

Answer (score 1):

There is a fixed bug to do with handling .owl files.  This maybe the issue for some of the exceptions you are seeing.  The current development snapshots have this fixed.

Unrelated:
You have the wrong version of xerces for jena.  You do not need icu4j anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The root error is a ClassNotFoundException for the following class: `org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.JenaReadersWriters$RDFReaderRIOT_RDFXML`. It looks like this library is using dynamic reflection to load the class, e.g. using `Class.forName()`, which is a really bad thing to do.

Anyway you should be able to fix it by adding the package `org.apache.jena.riot.adapters` to your Import-Package list.

Comment: Is it possible that the OP didn't try to load this by reflection, but that this is related to the [bug that @AndyS mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19414229/1281433)?

Comment: If the bug is that Jena uses Class.forName(), then it could be. You're right that OP is not using reflection directly himself, it's the library at fault.

Answer (score 0):

At last, it was certainly a problem of Jena libraries versions.

I solved it with the following ones:

```
xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1
com.ibm.icu/icu4j/3.4.4
org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1

com.hp.hpl.jena/arq/2.8.7
com.hp.hpl.jena/jena/2.6.4
com.hp.hpl.jena/iri/0.8
com.hp.hpl.jena/sdb/1.3.4
```

As Andy S. suggested me: "the problem is in the bundling.jena-core makes a reflection call to set up RIOT, and RIOT installs JenaReadersWriters$RDFReaderRIOT_RDFXML. This is instantiated with call of Class.newInstance(). It looks like the latter is failing.

This may be because of classloaders as setup by the OSGi bundling. You probably want one bundle with all of the Jena jars in it. As I understand your reported setup, you have a separate bundle, hence a different classloader, hence not found."

I have not checked it but probably the solution is to make a unique bundle jar with at least 2.11.0 version:

```
org.apache.jena/jena-core/2.11.0
org.apache.jena/jena-arq/2.11.0
org.apache.jena/jena-sdb/1.4.0
org.apache.jena/jena-iri/1.0.0
xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0`
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the post!!

I had the same issue and fixed it by just adding org.apache.jena.riot.adapters package at the imports of jena-core.jar.

E.g. BND configuration file of jena-core-2.11.1.jar:

```
version=2.11.1
Bundle-Version: ${version}
Bundle-Name: Jena CORE
Export-Package: !etc, !jena, !jena-log4j.properties, !jena.cmdline, !ont-policy.rdf, *; version=${version}
Import-Package: org.apache.jena.riot.adapters, *
```